# Object.prototype.valueOf() method

Tags: javascript

```
Object.prototype.valueOf.call("abc")
{ '0': 'a'
, '1': 'b'
, '2': 'c'
}
Object.prototype.valueOf.call(new String("abc"))
{ '0': 'a'
, '1': 'b'
, '2': 'c'
}
```

According to MDN JavaScript calls the valueOf method to convert an object to a primitive value.If an object has no primitive value, valueOf returns the object itself, which is displayed as:
*[object Object]*
But above valueOf is returning in different format rather than returning primitive
`{ '0': 'a'
    , '1': 'b'
    , '2': 'c'
    }`.Isn't it against the definition?Why is it returning in that format .Now,this has created confusion .How to know what will get returned if Object.prototype.valueOf.call(array) is called for array and other objects.

Also why the return object form `{}.valueOf()` gets displayed since returns from  `[].valueOf()` method when logged displays nothing

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at, what does the json piece do? : `{ '0': 'a'
, '1': 'b'
, '2': 'c'
}` ?

Comment: Where do you get `[object ObjectName]` from? Likely that is the result of calling toString on the returned object (such as when doing `alert(object)` or `console.log(object)`.

Comment: @RobG [object ObjectName] should be returned if valueOf() is called via Object.prototype.valueOf("string")

Comment: No, it shouldn't. You are calling *Object.prototype.valueOf* and passing a string primitive as *this*. So it gets converted to a String object and that is what is returned. [Read the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.4).

Comment: @Maizere: Do you confuse it with `Object.prototype.toString`?

Comment: @Bergi If an object has no primitive value, valueOf returns the object itself, which is displayed as: [object Object]. What will it return if object has primitive value like in above post but for different object ,how to know?

Comment: @Maizere: OK, your wording "returns object in [object String] format" was confusing. Still, the "which is displayed as" seems unecessary as we want to know *what* it is not how it is displayed. Btw: If you want to know what a native methods return in which cases exactly, [RTFM (or spec)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.49)

Comment: @Bergi [have a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at what [`valueOf`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.4) (that's a link) does:

> Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.

[ToObject](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9):

> String
>
> Create a new String object whose [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property is set to the value of the argument. See 15.5 for a description of String objects.

In other words, it simply creates a new string object with the original value, i.e. `new String('abc')`. Now take a look at how that is displayed in your console, and you'll notice it's the same as the `.valueOf.call` result.

Edit: This actually has more to do with what medium you use to view the answer. Chrome's and Firefox's dev tools display strings as their literal values (the string itself), but display string objects as if they were regular objects (by displaying their properties).

A string is just an "array" of characters with some methods on them. So the representation `{'0' : 'a', '1' : 'b', '2' : 'c'}` means "`a` in the first position, `b` in the second, `c` in the third", which is the string you asked for.

And as a final note, `valueOf` does not give `[object ObjectName]`. You may be referring to [`Object.prototype.toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I've missed what the actual question is. Here is what ECMA-262 says:

> 15.2.4.4 Object.prototype.valueOf ( )
>
> When the **valueOf** method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *O* be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the
>      argument.
> 2. If *O* is the result of calling the Object constructor with a
>      host object ([15.2.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1)), then
>
>    a. Return either *O* or another value such as
>      the host object originally passed to the constructor. The specific
>      result that is returned is implementation-defined.
> 3. Return *O*.

In the expression:

```
Object.prototype.valueOf.call("abc")
```

*Object.prototype.valueOf* is being called with a string primitive as *this*. So at step 1, it is converted using the internal [*ToObject*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) method.

If passed a value of Type String (which "abc" is) *ToObject* will return a String object.

Step 2 is irrelevant since the object is not a host object (it's a native object).

Step 3 returns the object created by *toObject*.

So test it:

```
var x = Object.prototype.valueOf.call("abc");

alert(typeof x); // object
```

*typeof* returns *object* because the resulting value is a String object (a nice quirk of the typeof operator). You can go further:

```
typeof x.match; // function
x.constructor;  // function String() {[native code]}
alert(x); // abc
```

All consistent with the returned value being (a reference to) a String object.

Comment: If an object has no primitive value, valueOf returns the object itself, which is displayed as: [object Object]. What will it return if object has primitive value like in above post but for different object ,how to know?

Comment: It's an object, so it has no primitive value (unless you count step 2)??? How do you expect it to have one?