# Javascript complicated valueOf method

Tags: javascript

What does `({}).valueOf.call(myvar)` do?

> *it converts any value to an object (an object remains unchanged, a primitive is converted to an instance of a wrapper type).*

My question is how?Can someone give The longer answer how this is done behind the scene.Since `valueOf()` method is meant to return primitive values not object .

```
console.log{name:"sameer"}.valueOf() //returns an object but cant be displayed since toString() method will be called by js so [object Object] gets displayed which is a string ,how to display the exact return value from valueOf() method .Is there a way?
```

Comment: `console.log(({name:"sameer"}).valueOf());` --> `Object {name: "sameer"}` but `{}` isn't a primitive therefore it returns the `toString()` since not many objects can return a primitive.

Comment: why do you think `valueOf` is only supposed to return primitives?

Comment: @Maizere you asked an eerie similar question yesterday. did it not help?

Comment: @limelights but this is not the dublicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559957/object-prototype-valueof-method)! Once more, we face the mighty opponent. Before we begin, let's dispel one false thought:

> valueOf() method is meant to return primitive values not object .

Not accurate. `valueOf` returns an object if a primitive value was passed to it. If you do `valueOf(object)`, you'd get the same object: `valueOf(object) === object`. You can trivially see that:

```
var obj = {};
obj.valueOf() === obj; //true
```

Now, for the more interesting question: How is `valueOf` defined? Let's look at the ES5 specification along with the v8 and spidermonkey sources.

`valueOf` ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.4), [v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/d9f3c73f3dd06df708014726b307d9001cfec7cd/src/v8natives.js#L244), [spidermonkey](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/15f32ad930343f949f3cd427e083f877c1a0f336/js/src/builtin/Object.cpp#L352)):

```
function ObjectValueOf() {
  return ToObject(this);
}
```

As we can see, it simply returns `ToObject`, as defined in the spec. The rabbit hole emerges.

`ToObject` ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9), [v8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/d9f3c73f3dd06df708014726b307d9001cfec7cd/src/runtime.js#L583), [spidermonkey](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/15f32ad930343f949f3cd427e083f877c1a0f336/js/src/jsobj.h#L1420))

```
function ToObject(x) {
  if (IS_STRING(x)) return new $String(x);
  if (IS_SYMBOL(x)) return new $Symbol(x);
  if (IS_NUMBER(x)) return new $Number(x);
  if (IS_BOOLEAN(x)) return new $Boolean(x);
  if (IS_NULL_OR_UNDEFINED(x) && !IS_UNDETECTABLE(x)) {
    throw %MakeTypeError('null_to_object', []);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Jackpot. We can see the entire flow here. If it's a string, number, boolean, etc return a wrapper (`$String` and `$Boolean` and the likes represent the actual String or Number; see [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/d9f3c73f3dd06df708014726b307d9001cfec7cd/src/runtime.js#L42)); if it's an invalid argument, throw an error; otherwise, return the argument.

The spidermonkey source for that one goes deeper down the rabbit hole. It defines `ToObject` as such:

```
JS_ALWAYS_INLINE JSObject *
ToObject(JSContext *cx, HandleValue vp)
{
    if (vp.isObject())
        return &vp.toObject();
    return ToObjectSlow(cx, vp, false);
}
```

So if it's not an Object, call `ToObjectSlow`. Buckle up Alice, there'll be C++. We need to take a look at what [`ToObejctSlow`](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/15f32ad930343f949f3cd427e083f877c1a0f336/js/src/jsobj.cpp#L4871) does:

```
JSObject *
js::ToObjectSlow(JSContext *cx, HandleValue val, bool reportScanStack)
{    
    if (val.isNullOrUndefined()) {
        ...error throwing magic here...
        return NULL;
    }

    return PrimitiveToObject(cx, val);
}
```

More indirection after looking whether the argument was null or undefined. The finale is [here](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/15f32ad930343f949f3cd427e083f877c1a0f336/js/src/jsobj.cpp#L4829):

```
JSObject *
PrimitiveToObject(JSContext *cx, const Value &v)
{
    if (v.isString()) {
        Rooted<JSString*> str(cx, v.toString());
        return StringObject::create(cx, str);
    }
    if (v.isNumber())
        return NumberObject::create(cx, v.toNumber());

    JS_ASSERT(v.isBoolean());
    return BooleanObject::create(cx, v.toBoolean());
}
```

Pretty much the same as the v8 version, only with different taxonomy.

---

Now, as I said before, I think your question has more to do with the medium of representing the object you see. Firebug and chrome's devtools are more than apt at displaying an object. However, if you try to `alert` it, you'll see the unfortunate `[object Object]`, because that's what `({}).toString()` gives you (since it gives out a string of the form `[object InternalClassName]`, again, as we've seen before).

As a bonus, try `console.dir({foo : 'bar'})`

Comment: this means only Object.prototype.valueOf() method returns wrapper object for primitive values.Am i correct?becz all other value of method returns primitive value

Comment: @maz `Object.prototype.valueOf` always returns an object wrapper. Things like strings and numbers override that function to return their own *primitive* representations. See the mirroring? `Object...valueOf` returns an object, `String...valueOf` returns a string, etc.

Answer (score 3):

**To answer your first question**

JavaScript has two main variable category types, primitives and Objects. You will often hear this, in JS everything is an Object. That is not entirely accurate. There are also primitive data types, which do nothing but hold values.

They have no methods and they are not instances of a wrapper type. So before you can call any method on them, they need to be converted to an object of the wrapper type. In JavaScript this conversion is automatic and it is called **auto-boxing**.

Allow me to demonstrate:

```
var firstString = "Test";
typeof firstString == "string"; // true

var secondString = new String("Test");
typeof secondString == "string"; // false
secondString.prototype.toString.call// [object String];
```

Notice what happens. There are actually two types above. One is `string` and the other one is `[object String]`. This tells you two things: `secondString instanceof String` is `true`. That is a wrapper type. Inside the core language you are seeing that `String` inherits from `Object`.

But the first `string` is just a memory reference, nothing more. When you call methods like `firstString.replace()`, `firstString` is automatically converted to its wrapper type. This is **autoboxing**.

The above behaviour stands for the following pairs:

**Number autoboxing**

`var x = 5; var y = new Number(5);`,

**Boolean autoboxing**

`var x = false; var y = new Boolean(false);`

**RegExp autoboxing**

`var x = new RegExp("etc"); var y = /etc/;`

**Object.prototype.valueOf**

The `valueOf` method is defined for any Object. In order for it to be called, it will convert all primitive types to their wrapper types and will leave existing objects unchanged. Now it will simply **return the value held in the Object reference**. So it's pretty simple and it is a way to **FORCE AUTOBOXING**. You are forcing the conversions I was mentioning earlier.

**To answer your second question**

Displaying the unfiltered result is simple. Use `console.dir()`.
Look [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bPU7m/1).

```
({}).valueOf.call(myvar);
```

It is the exact equivalent of `Object.prototype.valueOf.call(myVar);`. Now you already know what `valueOf` does.

Assuming you know the way `Function.prototype.call` works, your statement will call the `valueOf` method in the scope of the object you pass as a `this` argument to `Function.prototype.call`(the first parameter is the `this` object reference).

```
var myvar = {
    "name": "name"
};
({}).valueOf.call(myVar);
// is equivalent to
myVar.valueOf();
```

Comment: the result is due to the call of toString method.alert({}.valueOf()) ,the output is string again

Comment: it dont work sir in any browser.console.dir() what it does?

Comment: i m using the latest firefox why it is not working

Comment: have u checked ur suggestion ,it dont work on mine.Also ur post is incomplete ,what about my first question

Comment: thank u for ur post .i already have that even though i downloaded but still it dont work.Should it alert or write

Comment: I +1 this answer because it doesn't deserve a -1. It's complete, well explained and without errors.

Comment: @alex23 what is wrong with strict equality operator